# C++ constness on template type parameter

Tags: c++, templates, vector, constants, std-pair

I'm working with standard containers like vector and pair using custom types as template arguments. Most times these template types are const-qualified, as in:

```
std::vector<const std::pair<const customType, const double>>
```

Hash () operators and comparison operators == and < have been defined.

Problem arises when I'm passing such values to standard library functions like partial_sort_copy, partial_sort and erase. For some reason, those functions eventually try to make assignments on the given types, ultimately failing at compilation due to the consts.

Is there any way to cast the consts out on template types for vector and pair? I.e., casting `vector<const myType>` to `vector<myType>`.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT: Now with conflicting minimum sample code!**

```
// Non-working code:
std::vector<const std::pair<const int, const double>> list{ { 3, 3. }, { 2, 2. }, { 1, 1. }, { 0, 0. } };
std::partial_sort(list.begin(), list.begin() + 2, list.end(), [](const std::pair<const int, const double>& x, const std::pair<const int, const double>& y){ return x.first < y.first; });

// This works, actually:
std::vector<std::pair<int, double>> list{ { 3, 3. }, { 2, 2. }, { 1, 1. }, { 0, 0. } };
std::partial_sort(list.begin(), list.begin() + 2, list.end(), [](const std::pair<int, double>& x, const std::pair<int, double>& y){ return x.first < y.first; });
```

What is it about my code that the Standard Library won't like?

Comment: You probably should use non-const pairs of const values. Maybe defining an ADL-available `swap` would help, but you'll have to subclass `std::pair` since it is not a good idea to define anything in `std`.

Comment: thank you for your answer. i'll look up ADL.

Comment: @bipll It is totally admitted to define function overload/templates like `swap` and `hash` in std namespace.

Comment: Actually, I did so in the case of operator () of hash<type>

Comment: @Johan, but std::swap is not catched by the ADL, eh?

Comment: @bipl `vector` is in the std namespace and algorithm also. I totally admit that for `swap` it is not the best to define it in the `std` namespace because it will work only in `std` algorithm. But for the `hash`, it does greatly ease the writing by avoiding the repetition of the hasher on every map:

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/88a9c837f28a0694

Answer (score 4):

Such containers of const types are undefined behaviour. A `std::vector<const T>` uses `std::allocator<const T>` as its allocator type, and the Allocator requirements say that the value type must be a non-const object type.

Even ignoring that ...

> Is there any way to cast the consts out on template types for vector and pair? I.e., casting `vector<const myType>` to `vector<myType>`.

No.

In general `some_template<T>` and `some_template<const T>` are completely unrelated types, so you can't cast between them. There is no valid conversion between them, unlike `const some_template<T>` and `some_template<T>`.

So you should just stop using vectors of const objects. Instead use a const vector of non-const objects.

Comment: Hmmm. That's finally something. So why am I allowed to use such const constraints on templatised types if their behaviour is undefined? I also noticed that, while `const myType const *` is a valid type, using it for vector type is considered as a duplicated const qualifier. Is this somehow related to my stated issue? Thanks!

Comment: @jvier `const T*` and `T const*` are the same types. You probably meant `const T* const` (note the `const` after the star) instead.

Comment: @jvier "undefined behaviour" means you aren't allowed to do it, but the compiler is allowed to not give any warning message

Comment: @milleniumbug. you're right. i messed up. thanks for pointing it out.